# Ionic hide nav-bar not the buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to find a possible way to hide the ionic `ion-nav-bar` without hiding the `ion-nav-bar`buttons.
I have tried

```
hide-nav-bar="true"
```

but it is hiding buttons too. I have searched and also referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369120/hide-nav-bar-hides-nav-buttons-too-i-want-to-retain-the-view-title-and-the-ion), but nothing solved my problem. 
regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to specify what state want to hide the bar, and modify some styles

**JS:**

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

    var states = ['tabs.about', 'tabs.contact'];

    if(states.indexOf(toState.name) > -1) {
      $rootScope.hideBar=true;
    } else {
      $rootScope.hideBar=false;
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" ng-class="{ 'make-border-trasparent': hideBar }">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Please take a look at this example (I'm hiding the bar in the `tabs.about` and `tabs.contact` states)

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVmwzw)

Comment: thanks but its a thing I have already tried before and it is still not working for me. Does this works only on tabs as I am working on sidemenu app. And one more thing I didn't want to have nav-bar totally just want to use native sidemenu feature.

Comment: I built the same example in an sidemenu application and apparently it works perfectly: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXwGWJ

Comment: I am trying that. can u check this image, Can we get this type of view wth sidemenu button   https://www.dropbox.com/s/27cpnhmgk39403n/Screenshot_2016-05-04-14-28-58.png?dl=0

Comment: I understand what you need. It may be easier to hide all the nav-bar, add a button, and manually trigger the opening of the menu. with the $ionicSideMenuDelegate service you can control multiple aspects of the menu (to open: `$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();`)

Comment: @Atula Show this example (on Attendees content): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXwGWJ

Comment: you are really life saver for me.

Comment: great!

I would appreciate it would voteup to my answers :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110973/discussion-between-atula-and-felipecamposclarke).